# Android emulator has outdated Google Play Services

Tags: android-emulator, google-play-services

The latest Google Play Services version is 9.2.0
However Android emulator's Google Play Services is only 9.0.80

As a result, you cannot run an app compiled with 9.2.0 on the emulator. The MapView for example shows 'This app cannot run. Please update Google Play Services"

Any workaround other than changing app dependencies to 9.0.2?

Comment: I notice my "Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image" API 23 was Rev 12 and updated to Rev 14 and it still has 9.0.80. My guess is that we have to wait for a new image to be release with 9.2.0 installed. I couldn't find any release notes on emulator images. Would be nice if new images were released in tandem with Google Play Services.

Comment: Emulator images has received update today. Now it has google play services 9.2.56
I'm using X86_API23

Answer (score -1):

Add Google Play Services to your project, add `dependencies` for the latest version of `play-services`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
}
```

Be sure you update this version number each time Google Play services is updated.

As described in the [Google Play services overview](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview), Google Play delivers service updates for users on Android 2.3 and higher through the Google Play Store app. However, updates might not reach all users immediately, so your app should verify the version available before attempting to perform API transactions.

You are strongly encouraged to use the [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) class to access Google Play services features. This approach allows you to attach an `OnConnectionFailedListener` object to your client. To detect if the device has the appropriate version of the Google Play services APK, implement the `onConnectionFailed()` callback method. If the connection fails due to a missing or out-of-date version of the Google Play APK, the callback receives an error code such as `SERVICE_MISSING`, [SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult) or [SERVICE_DISABLED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult).

Comment: you're confusing google play service library, and google play services app on the emulator.
The whole point is that if you add dependency 9.2.0, the emulator doesn't work.